# How to fix the error "QtWidgets.abi3.so Reason: image not found" in Python on Mac OS X Catalina?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, pyqt, pyqt5

I am trying to run my python 3.9 code. I am on Mac OS X Catalina 10.15

I get an error when importing some PyQt5 modules:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui


From Pycharm, I get this error message:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Volumes/GoogleDrive/My Drive/project/main.py", line 135, in <module>
    from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/QtWidgets.abi3.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/QtWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWidgets
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/QtWidgets.abi3.so
  Reason: image not found
```

from terminal, I get this error:

```
dyld: loaded: <9D893D18-53D8-3C59-80F1-3E37DF41D246> /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/QtWidgets.abi3.so
dyld: unloaded: <9D893D18-53D8-3C59-80F1-3E37DF41D246> /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/QtWidgets.abi3.so
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Volumes/GoogleDrive/My Drive/project/main.py", line 135, in <module>
    from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/QtWidgets.abi3.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/QtWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWidgets
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/QtWidgets.abi3.so
  Reason: image not found
```

I tried to upgrade pyqt5 with the command:

```
 python3 -m pip install PyQt5 upgrade
```

but I get this error message:

```
Requirement already satisfied: PyQt5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (5.15.4)
dyld: loaded: <F1258E44-15BC-3DBB-8563-B8703B358AD9> /usr/lib/libusrtcp.dylib
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement upgrade (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for upgrade
```

I. checked with :

```
python3 -m pip freeze
```

Here are all the PyQt5 modules I have:

```
PyQt3D==5.15.5
PyQt5==5.15.4
PyQt5-Qt5==5.15.2
PyQt5-sip==12.9.0
PyQt5-stubs==5.15.2.0
PyQt6==6.2.0
PyQt6-3D==6.2.0
PyQt6-Charts==6.2.0
PyQt6-DataVisualization==6.2.0
PyQt6-NetworkAuth==6.2.0
PyQt6-sip==13.1.0
PyQtChart==5.15.5
PyQtDataVisualization==5.15.5
PyQtNetworkAuth==5.15.5
PyQtPurchasing==5.15.5
PyQtWebEngine==5.15.5
PyQtWebEngine-Qt5==5.15.2
```

So I try with Homebrew :

```
brew install pyqt5
```

and I get this output:

```
Warning: pyqt@5 5.15.6 is already installed and up-to-date.
To reinstall 5.15.6, run:
  brew reinstall pyqt@5
```

I search help on forum and I read some solution in my .zshrc file:

```
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-15.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home:/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages:/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PySide2"

PATH="/usr/local/bin:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-15.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_271.jdk/Contents/Home:/Users/alisa/.wdm/drivers/geckodriver/macos/v0.30.0:/Users/alisa/Android/cmdline-tools/latest/bin:/Users/alisa/Android/platform-tools:/bin:/opt/local/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/:/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.12_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/:/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.12_1/bin/:/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages:/usr/local/opt/qt@/bin/:/usr/local/opt/qt@6/bin/:/usr/sbin/"
```

My file seems fine or did I forgot something?

Can anyone help me please to fix this issue?